# Why i cant get value of input

Tags: javascript

I cant get value of inputs to create rectangle on page after click. I thought it because of event loop and tried to wrap it in setTimeout() but it doesn't work out. So what should I do and how it actually work?
Code:

```js
(() => {
    const inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    const inputs = {
        height: setTimeout(() => {return inputElements[0].value},0),
        width: inputElements[1].value || 50 
    }

    const elements = [];
    const bodyClick = document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
        event.target.tagName !== "INPUT" ? addRectangle(): formClick();
    })
    const addRectangle = () => {
        let newRectangle = document.createElement('div');
        newRectangle.style.background = getRandomColor();
        newRectangle.style.width = inputs.width + 'px';
        console.log(inputs.width)
        newRectangle.style.height = inputs.height +'px';
        document.body.appendChild(newRectangle);
        elements.push(newRectangle);
    }
    const formClick = () => {

    }
    const getRandomColor = () => {
        let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        let color = '#';
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }
})()
```

```css
body {
    height: 1000px;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Lab 6</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id = "form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="height">
        <input type="text" placeholder="width">
    </form>
<script src="source.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Issues: 1. setTimeout does not return anything. 2. While creating rectangle, you are taking values from `inputs` which is initialized once. So newly added values are not accepted.

Comment: You're using `const` for the `inputs` variable, so I expect it's probably always got blank values for width and height, as the input fields values are blank on initial load.

Comment: @DBS thats not the issue. OP is not accepting values anywhere. On page load, both values are blank. So height is set to undefined and width is set to default 50.

Comment: @Rajesh I'm not sure what your point is, isn't that what I just said? The use of const and the lack of the variable being updated are two sides of the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(() => {
    const inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    const elements = [];
    const bodyClick = document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
        event.target.tagName !== "INPUT" ? addRectangle(): formClick();
    })
    const addRectangle = () => {
        const inputs = {
          height: inputElements[0].value || 50,
          width: inputElements[1].value || 50 
        }
        let newRectangle = document.createElement('div');
        newRectangle.style.background = getRandomColor();
        newRectangle.style.width = inputs.width + 'px';
        newRectangle.style.height = inputs.height +'px';
        document.body.appendChild(newRectangle);
        elements.push(newRectangle);
    }
    const formClick = () => {

    }
    const getRandomColor = () => {
        let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        let color = '#';
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }
})()
```

```css
body {
    height: 1000px;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<form id = "form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="height">
    <input type="text" placeholder="width">
</form>
```

`setTimeout` wont return value to you.

On body click get the values for input then set it to created div.

Comment: Thanks. and there is on way to leave this object out of callback?

Comment: @GlebZ. input object?

Comment: If you declare it globally you can access it.